# Python: How to solve a set of nonlinear equations with multiple solutions

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, sympy, polynomials

I want to solve a set of three nonlinear equations. Something like

```
f1 = 1.02226923451805*x**2 - 1.9683360808094*x*y + 1.03639538768756*y**2 - 49
f2 = 1.03639538768756*y**2 - 2.03796060801355*y*z + 1.04842646546047*z**2 - 25
f3 = 1.02226923451805*x**2 - 1.93479820599624*x*z + 1.04842646546047*z**2 - 74
```

In Matlab I can use solve and get eight solutions:

```
-20.3224 -22.8100 -23.1694
-23.5467 -22.9631 -23.1503
-23.6222 -22.1818 -23.0558
-23.6372 -22.4943 -20.5865
23.6372 22.4943 20.5865
23.6222 22.1818 23.0558
23.5467 22.9631 23.1503
20.3224 22.8100 23.1694
```

In python I've tried using sympy's solve_poly_equations but it returns None. I've also tried scipy's fsolve but this only returns one solution based on an initial guess.

```
from sympy import solve_poly_system
from sympy.abc import x,y,z
f1 = 1.02226923451805*x**2 - 1.9683360808094*x*y + 1.03639538768756*y**2 - 49 
f2 = 1.03639538768756*y**2 - 2.03796060801355*y*z + 1.04842646546047*z**2 - 25 
f3 = 1.02226923451805*x**2 - 1.93479820599624*x*z + 1.04842646546047*z**2 - 74 
s = solve_poly_system([f1, f2, f3], x, y, z)
print(s)
>> None

from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def myFunc(v):
    x = v[0]
    y = v[1]
    z = v[2]
    f = empty((3))
    f[0] = 1.02226923451805*x**2 - 1.9683360808094*x*y + 1.03639538768756*y**2 - 49 
    f[1] = 1.03639538768756*y**2 - 2.03796060801355*y*z + 1.04842646546047*z**2 - 25 
    f[2] = 1.02226923451805*x**2 - 1.93479820599624*x*z + 1.04842646546047*z**2 - 74 
    return f
s = fsolve(myFunction, [1, 1, 1])   
print(s)
>> [23.63719275 22.49425691 20.58646335]
```

I'm trying to solve a problem where it is important that all possible solutions are returned. Is there a way in Python to get all eight solutions like Matlab is giving?

Comment: Getting all the roots for a nonlinear set of equations is not a trivial task. As far as I remember, even Matlab's fsolve only gives one root. Which matlab solver are you referring to ?

Comment: @AxeonThra I am using this solver. [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) It returns 8 values for x, y, z.